# Deadlock in a small MultiThreading application

Tags: java, multithreading

I have just started studying multithreading and I wrote a code to understand that. Unfortunately I'm stuck with a deadlock and can't figure out how to solve that.

Simple Producer Consumer Problem.

Teacher generates a number, puts it on table, notifies the students, students check if the number is what they need, they pick it up, notify the teacher, and teacher again generates a number.

Problem : The code stops after the teacher produces a random number and notifies the students

Output is something like this:

Created S1

Created S2

Created S3

Created Teacher

waiting S1

waiting S3

waiting S2

3

Notified

Code :

```
public class Student extends Thread{
    String name;
    int held;
    int needed;
    Table tab;

    Student(String name, int held, Table tab){
        this.name = name;
        this.held = held;
        needed = 7 - held; 
        this.tab = tab;
        System.out.println("Created " + name);
    }

    public void run(){

        while(true){
            synchronized(this){
                while(tab.contains() == 0){
                    try{
                        System.out.println("waiting " + name);
                        wait();
                        System.out.println("wait over in loop");
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.println("Err!");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("wait over" + name);
                if(tab.contains() == needed){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tab.remove();
                    System.out.println("Drawing made by " + name);
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}




    public class Teacher extends Thread{
        String name;
        Table tab;
        public Teacher(String name, Table tab){


    this.name = name;
        this.tab = tab;
        System.out.println("Created " + name);
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            while(true){
                while(tab.contains()>0){
                    try{
                        wait();
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.println("Boo");
                    }
                }
                int value = 0;
                while ((value != 3) && (value != 5) && (value != 6)){ 
                    value = (int)(1 + Math.random()*7);
                }
                tab.put(value);
                notifyAll();

                System.out.println(value);
                System.out.println("Notified");
            }
        }
    }   
}



public class Table {
    int value;

    public synchronized void put(int n){
        this.value = n;
    }

    public synchronized int remove(){
        System.out.println("Value removed" + value);
        int temp = value;
        value = 0;
        return temp;
    }

    public int contains(){
        return this.value;
    }

}

package LabTest;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Table tab = new Table();
        Thread ST1 = new Student("S1",4,tab);
        Thread ST2 = new Student("S2",2,tab);
        Thread ST3 = new Student("S3",1,tab);
        Thread Teach = new Teacher("Teacher",tab); 
        ST1.start();
        ST2.start();
        ST3.start();
        Teach.start();

        try {
            ST1.join();
            ST2.join();
            ST3.join();
            Teach.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Most of this question seems to be a homework assignment that is unrelated to the problem at hand. You should remove all that, since it is useless and will make people less likely to help you. (Pretty much all the text starting with "Problem").

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you showed a printout of the thread messages.

Comment: Oh, so you *edited* your post to remove the obvious homework directions.  Nice job there.  Now we don't have any information at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its not a homework thing, I got this question from the internet. I'd really appreciate if you could provide me with links to any other problems to practice for multithreading.

Comment: See the two answers. Essentially, the while loop in your teacher results in the teacher only generating the values 3, 5, or 6. EDIT: I just saw your edit - in your example, the teacher generated the value 3. That should have been your giveaway that you created deadlock.

Comment: Basically, my 3 students have 4,2 and 1 as their initial values. They are waiting for 3, 5 or 6. That is why 'Teacher' is generating these values. if 3 is produced student with initial value 4 picks it up to get a total of 7. Similarly for the other 2 students also. Please tell me if I misunderstand what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some fundamental flaws.  Both the Teacher and Student classes include `synchronized (this)` and `wait()` and `notifyAll()`, but based on the way you're using them I think you don't really understand that each of these constructs acts only on the specific instance in question.

For instance, when a Student thread enters `wait`, it will remain in that state until some other thread calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` *on that instance*.

Very specifically `x.notifyAll()` doesn't wake up every thread that is doing any kind of waiting.  It only wakes up something that has previously done `x.wait()`, where `x` is the exact same object.

In order to do this kind of cross thread synchronization, there needs to be a *shared object* on which all threads act.  Since the `Table` object is shared by all the instances, that seems like the obvious candidate.  So for a first pass I would replace all `wait()` with `tab.wait()` and `notifyAll()` with `tab.notifyAll()` and drop the `synchronized(this)`.

This will likely get you closer to the functionality you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That was exactly where I was doing the mistake. Now there is no deadlock. I had read this concept in the book but couldn't really understand it there. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Could you please suggest me some more problems for practice? I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this code in your teacher:

```
int value = 0;
while ((value != 3) && (value != 5) && (value != 6)){ 
  value = (int)(1 + Math.random()*7);
}
```

So, let us imagine we are the computer:

1. We set value = 0
2. We check the while loop condition:
3. value is not 3 and value is not 5 and value is not 6
4. We pick another value
5. Say 1.
6. value is not 3 and not 5 and not 6
7. We pick another value
8. Say 3.
9. This causes us to exit the while loop.
10. We notify the students.
11. Nobody is waiting for 3, 5, or 6 (the only values that will terminate the while loop)
12. Nobody ever removes a value from the table.
13. Teacher never generates new values.
14. Deadlock reached!

Comment: This looks like a valid concern, but re:10 ... the students never wake up because the students are not waiting on the teacher, they're waiting on themselves.  If they did the output would contain that they've woken up from their loop, regardless of what values the table contains.

Comment: @Jherico They will wake up then immediately go back to sleep, never to wake again. Hmm, it appears we have both individually put up part of the problem. Want to merge my answer in with yours?